# How to display Radius after Resizing a Feature in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, cartography, area, html

@captDragon has helped me with calling the coordinates of a polygon after I have resized or dragged the feature. Ineed the radius now, i have done a radius alert on my other map,Which works correctly, I,m trying to replace the following code:

```
    vectors.events.on({
      featuremodified: featureModified
      });

     function featureModified(event) {

    var bounds = event.feature.geometry.getBounds();
    var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
    answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
    answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
    answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
    alert(answer);
    }
```

With this code

```
    function onFeaturesAdded(circle) {
       var area = circle.geometry.getArea();
       var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(area);
       alert(radius);
       }
```

I tried

```
       function featureModified(event) {
       var area = event.geometry.getArea();
       var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(area);
       alert(radius);
       }
```

But this does not work. Below is my working file:

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <!--CSS for Map -->
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map {
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- END of CSS for Map -->

    <!--CSS for Controls to draw circle and navigate -->
    <style type="text/css">
    #controls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 20000;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    }

   #controlToggle {
    padding-left: 1em;
   }

   #controlToggle li {
    list-style: none;
   }

   #form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 20000;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    }
   </style>
   <!-- END CSS for Controls to draw circle -->

   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="js/firebug.js"></script>
   <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    var lon = 24.0000000000;
    var lat = -29.000000000000;

    var zoom = 4;
    var map, layer, vectors, controls;

    function init() {




  // Because the Streetmaps system uses 300x300 tiles, we need to set up the scaling variables to work with these
  var aRes = [90, 45, 22.500000, 11.250000, 5.625000, 2.812500, 1.406250, 0.703125, 0.351563, 0.175781, 0.087891, 0.043945, 0.021973, 0.010986, 0.005493, 0.002747, 0.001373, 0.000687, 0.000343];
  for (var l = 0; l < aRes.length; l++) { aRes[l] = aRes[l] / 300; }

  // Normal init, but we pass through the info about the zoom/scaling as options
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(300, 300), projection: 'CRS:84', numZoomLevels: aRes.length, resolutions: aRes, maxResolution: 360 / 300 });

  // At this point the control is used as per normal            
  layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                  'Streetmaps Streets',
                  'http://www.streetmaps.co.za/WMS/?',
                  {
                      key: 'HZPGNWPNDYPREPTIKSIHWKYKQYYOQVYX',
                      service: 'WMS',
                      request: 'GetMap',
                      version: '1.3.0',
                      layers: 'sm.maps.tiled',
                      format: 'image/png'
                  }
        );

  layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                  'Streetmaps Imagery',
                  'http://www.streetmaps.co.za/WMS/?',
                  {
                      key: 'HZPGNWPNDYPREPTIKSIHWKYKQYYOQVYX',
                      service: 'WMS',
                      request: 'GetMap',
                      version: '1.3.0',
                      layers: 'sm.imagery',
                      format: 'image/png'
                  }
        );

  // This loads the map
  map.addLayer(layer1);
  map.addLayer(layer2);

  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
  var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", { isBaseLayer: true });
  map.addLayers([vectors]);



  // This loads the overlays
  var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", { layers: 'basic' });
  OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']['strokeWidth'] = '2';

  // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
  var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
  renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

  vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
      renderers: renderer
  });

  map.addLayers([wms, vectors]);
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
  map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);



  // Now we call an alert to get the bounds or coordinates from a circle or vector we have drawn 
  vectors.events.on({
      featuresadded: onFeaturesAdded
  });

  function onFeaturesAdded(event) {
      var bounds = event.features[0].geometry.getBounds();
      var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
      answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
      answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
      answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
      alert(answer);
  }

  vectors.events.on({
      afterfeaturemodified: afterFeatureModified
  });

  function afterFeatureModified(event) {
      var bounds = event.features[0].geometry.getBounds();
      var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
      answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
      answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
      answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
      alert(answer);
  }


  controls = {
      regular: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon,
                { handlerOptions: { sides: 40} }),
      modify: new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectors)
  };

  for (var key in controls) {
      map.addControl(controls[key]);
  }

  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);
  document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;
   }


  function update() {
  // reset modification mode
  //controls.modify.mode = OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE;
  controls["modify"].activate();
  controls.modify.mode = OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.ROTATE;

  var resize = document.getElementById("resize").checked;
  if (resize) {
      controls.modify.mode |= OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESIZE;
      var keepAspectRatio = document.getElementById("keepAspectRatio").checked;
      if (keepAspectRatio) {
          controls.modify.mode &= ~OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE;
      }
  }
  var drag = document.getElementById("drag").checked;
  if (drag) {
      controls.modify.mode |= OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.DRAG;
  }

  //          if (rotate || drag) {
  //              controls.modify.mode &= ~OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE;
  //          }
  //          var sides = parseInt(document.getElementById("sides").value);
  //          sides = Math.max(3, isNaN(sides) ? 0 : sides);
  //          controls.regular.handler.sides = sides;
  //          var irregular = document.getElementById("irregular").checked;
  //          controls.regular.handler.irregular = irregular;
 }


function toggleControl(element) {
  for (key in controls) {
      var control = controls[key];
      if (element.value == key && element.checked) {
          control.activate();
      } else {
          control.deactivate();
      }
  }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="init()">
 <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
<div id="controls">
 <ul id="controlToggle">
   <li>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle"
           onclick="toggleControl(this);" checked="checked" />

      <label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>
  </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="regular" id="regularToggle" onClick="toggleControl(this);" />
    <label for="regularToggle">draw regular polygon</label>
  </li>
  <li>
       <input type="radio" name="type" value="modify" id="modifyToggle"
           onclick="update();" />

          <label for="modifyToggle">modify feature</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
              <input id="rotate" type="hidden" 
                   name="rotate" onChange="update()"  checked="checked"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="resize" type="hidden"
                   name="resize" onChange="update()"  checked="checked"/>
            <input id="keepAspectRatio" type="hidden"
                   name="keepAspectRatio" onChange="update()" checked="checked" />
            <label for="keepAspectRatio"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="drag" type="hidden"
                   name="drag" onChange="update()"  checked="checked"/>
        </li>

      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `var area = event.geometry.getArea();` should be `var area = event.feature.geometry.getArea();`

So i believe this is what you're looking for:

```js
   vectors.events.on({
       featuremodified: featureModified
   });

   function featureModified(event) {
       var area = event.feature.geometry.getArea();
       var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(area);
       alert(radius);
   }
```

Here's the modified full working code:

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <!--CSS for Map -->
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map {
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- END of CSS for Map -->

    <!--CSS for Controls to draw circle and navigate -->
    <style type="text/css">
    #controls {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 20000;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    }

   #controlToggle {
    padding-left: 1em;
   }

   #controlToggle li {
    list-style: none;
   }

   #form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 20000;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    }
   </style>
   <!-- END CSS for Controls to draw circle -->

   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="js/firebug.js"></script>
   <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var lon = 24.0000000000;
       var lat = -29.000000000000;

       var zoom = 4;
       var map, layer, vectors, controls;

       function init() {




           // Because the Streetmaps system uses 300x300 tiles, we need to set up the scaling variables to work with these
           var aRes = [90, 45, 22.500000, 11.250000, 5.625000, 2.812500, 1.406250, 0.703125, 0.351563, 0.175781, 0.087891, 0.043945, 0.021973, 0.010986, 0.005493, 0.002747, 0.001373, 0.000687, 0.000343];
           for (var l = 0; l < aRes.length; l++) { aRes[l] = aRes[l] / 300; }

           // Normal init, but we pass through the info about the zoom/scaling as options
           map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(300, 300), projection: 'CRS:84', numZoomLevels: aRes.length, resolutions: aRes, maxResolution: 360 / 300 });

           // At this point the control is used as per normal            
           layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                  'Streetmaps Streets',
                  'http://www.streetmaps.co.za/WMS/?',
                  {
                      key: 'HZPGNWPNDYPREPTIKSIHWKYKQYYOQVYX',
                      service: 'WMS',
                      request: 'GetMap',
                      version: '1.3.0',
                      layers: 'sm.maps.tiled',
                      format: 'image/png'
                  }
        );

           layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                  'Streetmaps Imagery',
                  'http://www.streetmaps.co.za/WMS/?',
                  {
                      key: 'HZPGNWPNDYPREPTIKSIHWKYKQYYOQVYX',
                      service: 'WMS',
                      request: 'GetMap',
                      version: '1.3.0',
                      layers: 'sm.imagery',
                      format: 'image/png'
                  }
        );

           // This loads the map
           map.addLayer(layer1);
           map.addLayer(layer2);

           map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
           map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
           var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", { isBaseLayer: true });
           map.addLayers([vectors]);



           // This loads the overlays
           var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", { layers: 'basic' });
           OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']['strokeWidth'] = '2';

           // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
           var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
           renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

           vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
               renderers: renderer
           });

           map.addLayers([wms, vectors]);
           map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
           map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
           map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);



           // Now we call an alert to get the bounds or coordinates from a circle or vector we have drawn 
           vectors.events.on({
               featuresadded: onFeaturesAdded
           });

           function onFeaturesAdded(event) {
               var bounds = event.features[0].geometry.getBounds();
               var answer = "bottom: " + bounds.bottom + "\n";
               answer += "left: " + bounds.left + "\n";
               answer += "right: " + bounds.right + "\n";
               answer += "top: " + bounds.top + "\n";
               alert(answer);
           }

           vectors.events.on({
               featuremodified: featureModified
           });

           function featureModified(event) {
               var area = event.feature.geometry.getArea();
               var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(area);
               alert(radius);
           }


           controls = {
               regular: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon,
                { handlerOptions: { sides: 40} }),
               modify: new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vectors)
           };

           for (var key in controls) {
               map.addControl(controls[key]);
           }

           map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);
           document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;
       }


       function update() {
           // reset modification mode
           //controls.modify.mode = OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE;
           controls["modify"].activate();
           controls.modify.mode = OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.ROTATE;

           var resize = document.getElementById("resize").checked;
           if (resize) {
               controls.modify.mode |= OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESIZE;
               var keepAspectRatio = document.getElementById("keepAspectRatio").checked;
               if (keepAspectRatio) {
                   controls.modify.mode &= ~OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE;
               }
           }
           var drag = document.getElementById("drag").checked;
           if (drag) {
               controls.modify.mode |= OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.DRAG;
           }

           //          if (rotate || drag) {
           //              controls.modify.mode &= ~OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESHAPE;
           //          }
           //          var sides = parseInt(document.getElementById("sides").value);
           //          sides = Math.max(3, isNaN(sides) ? 0 : sides);
           //          controls.regular.handler.sides = sides;
           //          var irregular = document.getElementById("irregular").checked;
           //          controls.regular.handler.irregular = irregular;
       }


       function toggleControl(element) {
           for (key in controls) {
               var control = controls[key];
               if (element.value == key && element.checked) {
                   control.activate();
               } else {
                   control.deactivate();
               }
           }
       }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="init()">
 <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
<div id="controls">
 <ul id="controlToggle">
   <li>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle"
           onclick="toggleControl(this);" checked="checked" />

      <label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>
  </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="regular" id="regularToggle" onClick="toggleControl(this);" />
    <label for="regularToggle">draw regular polygon</label>
  </li>
  <li>
       <input type="radio" name="type" value="modify" id="modifyToggle"
           onclick="update();" />

          <label for="modifyToggle">modify feature</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
              <input id="rotate" type="hidden" 
                   name="rotate" onChange="update()"  checked="checked"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="resize" type="hidden"
                   name="resize" onChange="update()"  checked="checked"/>
            <input id="keepAspectRatio" type="hidden"
                   name="keepAspectRatio" onChange="update()" checked="checked" />
            <label for="keepAspectRatio"></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="drag" type="hidden"
                   name="drag" onChange="update()"  checked="checked"/>
        </li>

      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Anytime my pleasure